# JavaScript OR (II) (this OR this OR this... do this)

Tags: operator-keyword

I am trying to build, rock, paper scissor in JavaScript and I have problem with implementing safety precautions.

Here's my code:

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
if (userChoice !== "rock" || "Rock" || "ROCK" || "paper"|| "Paper"|| "PAPER" || "scissors"|| "Scissors"|| "SCISSORS") {
console.log("Please, enter valid data: 'rock', 'paper', or 'scissors' (without parentheses)."); 
}
else 
console.log("Voila!");
```

Let´s suppose my code for game itself work (I have supplemented it with 'console.log("Voila!");' part).

What I am unable to do, is checking for improper input from user.
First, formerly I have used in the second line '!===', which does not seem to exist.
When I replaced it with '!==' program works, but incorrectly.
When I type string 'rock' I, as a user, will always win.
if I type 'Rock' it will give me output from line 3, which it shouldn't.

So I suppose my way of 'if this OR this OR this... do this' is not correct.
Can anybody point me to where I am making mistake?

Comment: `val !== a || b || c` does not check the value of `val` against the values `a`, `b` and `c` as you think it does, the correct form is `if (val !== a && val !== b && val !== c)`

Comment: Consider using `.toUpperCase()` then comparing with "ROCK" so rock in any case is accepted.

Comment: Hint: `userChoice.match(/^(rock|paper|scissors)$/i)`…

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. For now, I have done what Alex K. wrote and it's working as it should. though answer from deceze is definitely something I should look up for the future (match + regular expressions) :) Also, my question being marked as duplicate - I was trying to find similar questions before I have posted mine, but I did not.  Hope that doesn´t go against the rules here.